# Match_parent height inside layout with wrap_content height

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to cover my entire list item with a shadow drawable on the right side.

Problem is that my layout wrapping the drawable has not a constant height. I tired to set my drawable to align parent top and align parent bottom but it still does not stretch the entire height of its parent layout.

look att the shadow on the right (I've provided a min height property to make it visible, the forth list item is bigger than min view, and the shadow does not stretch)

[image]

Source:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/list_item_header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_news_thumb"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/listview_one_row"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/listview_one_row"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_news_thumb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_news_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_m"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_s"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_news_thumb"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_m"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_news_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_news_title"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/space_m"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_s"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_news_thumb"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/space_m"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/font_light" />

        **<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_news_list_shadow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img_news_thumb"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/listview_one_row"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/list_shadow_r" />**

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_selected_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/list_item_arrow"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/list_item_devider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you use normal pngs for the shadows or do you use stretchable niner pngs? http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: try android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" for the list item containing layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to recent investigations, i've found out that the answer is much simpler than that.

When inflating the layout, we should use this:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
```

Instead of the commonly used error:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out it is not possible since the parent layout ie linear layout in this case always wraps content when used in a listview.