# Set ImageView height to fit his parent in a ListView

Tags: android, imageview

I have a 5x5 ImageView and I want his height stretch to fit the height of his parent.
I don't want keep aspect ratio, but only 100% height of the row of the ScrollList.

Using this code the image fits perfectly, but only AFTER I scroll the listview:

```
ImageView imageSemaforo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.semaforo);
RelativeLayout LayoutRiga = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.RowRelativeLayout);
int altezzaRIga = LayoutRiga.getHeight();
LayoutParams parmaImage = imageSemaforo.getLayoutParams();
parmaImage.height = altezzaRIga;
imageSemaforo.setLayoutParams(parmaImage);
```

Comment: Add `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to the ImageView in XML.

Comment: Thanks Mike, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz I don't think you can use both at the same time :/ I will double check. I had the same issue and I was able to fix it.

Comment: @Alessandro My answer above worked for me. I just tested it. I suspect your issue is that the parent height is `wrap_content`, in which case you will have troubles trying to match its height in XML. Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082793/match-parent-height-inside-layout-with-wrap-content-height) for more info.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz, I checked: my parent layout is a RelativeLayout with both fill_parent` as value of layout_width/layout_height. Addind the  line : `LayoutRiga.measure(0, 0)`; in the code above everything work!

Comment: @Alessandro if you solved your own problem, you should officially add an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for point it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I addedd these lines to my code:

```
RelativeLayout LayoutRiga = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.RowRelativeLayout);
LayoutRiga.measure(0, 0); 
int altezzaRIga =LayoutRiga.getMeasuredHeight();
LayoutParams parmaImage = imageSemaforo.getLayoutParams();
imageSemaforo.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
parmaImage.height = altezzaRIga;
imageSemaforo.setLayoutParams(parmaImage);
```

Note le line:

```
 LayoutRiga.measure(0, 0);
```

I had to add this in order to have everything work; otherwise the first time the Listview is created the ImageView is empty until you scroll the list.